# Auto-resize IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, resize

I really need someone's help on this> I have a little image inside an IFrame that upon being clicked on, will display another image and slide down a little. How can I make the IFrame automatically get bigger or smaller, according to its contents?

Thank you so much!

***edit**
After researching this more, I have found quite a few examples that claim (i have not tested them) to do what I need, but ONLY after a page-refresh. Which is something I cannot do.

Comment: In order to do this easily (or reliably) your parent page and iframed page need to be on the same domain. Can you confirm whether this is the case so we know how to answer?

Comment: I can confirm that unfortunately no, this is not the case. The IFrames are not all hosted on the same domain.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I think that there isn't any solution that is secure. All solutions that I've found seem to pose major security threats. Time to close this question, I think - no real point in having it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size of your iFrame using a [**JavaScript**](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=102223) method. Then you associate that method to your iFrame's OnLoad event.

There was no point re-authoring the code as it is short and to the point in the above link.
One person said it doesn't work in Opera but try it and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Yeah, sorry Francois, the code from the link above really doesn't work. Thanks for trying though. :)

Comment: Okay, after reading a lot more about IFrames, and scouring the web for a few weeks I was able to pick up a few things here and there, and apply it to the code sample demonstrated in the link you provided. So, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can auto resize your iframe without an iframes on load event or any of that.  But i only tested in ie7 + and it works in 3.6+ firefox and chrome.

Here is what i came up with.

```
var $app = $(window[options.name]),
            $appContainer = $("#app-runner");

        window.setInterval(function() {
            var frameEl = $app[0].frameElement,
                frameDoc = 0,
                height = 0;

            if (frameEl.contentDocument !== undefined) {
                frameDoc = frameEl.contentDocument,
                height = frameDoc.height || frameDoc.body.offsetHeight;
            } else if (frameEl.document !== undefined && frameEl.document.documentElement !== undefined) {
                frameDoc = frameEl.document.documentElement,
                height = frameDoc.offsetHeight;
            }
            $appContainer.css("height", height);
        }, 500);
```

Obviously there are better choices for better performance.  But this is what i came up with.  The html is simple.  Just ahve an iframe wrapped in a div with id === "app-runner".  The iframe should have height = 100%.  This way, no scroll bars are needed, app just auto resizes on every 500ms (better and quicker results = more processor time required)

Comment: it requires jQuery, right? using jQuery v1.8.3, there is an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined`. The script is loaded after document is ready